# OSL Texture Mapping

Tags: scripting, shaders, texture-coordinates, osl

I'm new to OSL and Blender. I'm using the following code to generate a circle on a plane. The plane, however, appears to be split into two triangles. Can anyone explain how to fix this so my OSL circle is mapped correctly? Thank you!

```
shader Circle(
        float rad=0.75 [[float min=0, float max=1]],
        float sharp=0.8 [[float min=0, float max=1]],
        int rep=1[[int min=1, int max=10]],
        point cent=point(0.5, 0.5, 0),
    output color c = 0)
{
    point pt = point(rep*u, rep*v,0);
    float ctx = floor(pt[0])+cent[0];
    float cty = floor(pt[1])+cent[1];
    point ct = point(ctx, cty, 0);
    float d = fmod(distance(ct, pt), rep)/rad;

    c = 1-smoothstep(0.5*sharp, 1-0.5*sharp, d);

}
```

[image: Viewport]

Comment: See also https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/24525/transform-texture-coords-within-osl for you usage of u and v instead of P

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`u` and `v` are global variables provided by OSL. They refer to the *parametric* U and V; the normalized [barycentric coordinates](https://www.scratchapixel.com/lessons/3d-basic-rendering/ray-tracing-rendering-a-triangle/barycentric-coordinates) of the shading point in the currently shaded triangle. They are the same U and V as are returned in the  2D vector you get from the *Geometry* node > *Parametric* output.

To get the U and V of the quad, as mapped, you have to look up the U and V from the object's active UV map, using `getattribute()` :

```
shader Circle(
        float radius = 0.75,
        float sharpness = 0.8,
        int tiles = 1,
        point center = point(0.5, 0.5, 0.0),
        output color c = (0.0) 
        )
{
    vector UV = (0.0);
    int hasUV = getattribute( "geom:uv", UV);
  
    point pt = point(tiles*UV[0], tiles*UV[1],0);
    float ctx = floor(pt[0])+center[0];
    float cty = floor(pt[1])+center[1];
    point ct = point(ctx, cty, 0);
    float d = fmod(distance(ct, pt), tiles)/radius;

    c = 1-smoothstep(0.5*sharpness, 1-0.5*sharpness, d);
}
```

.. but here, we run into an [unfulfilled promise](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/render/shader_nodes/osl.html?highlight=getattr#attributes) in the Blender manual, which judging by the age of [this answer](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/24550/35559), you might expect to have been fixed by now. Bizarrely, as far as the user is concerned, Blender's implementation of OSL refuses to give a value to `geom:uv`, unless there is an *Image Texture* node somewhere in the tree. (If you want to evaluate some other UV map by name in your OSL, the tree must also contain a like-named UV Map node, connected to the *Image Texture* node.)

So your tree winds up looking like this:

[image]

I hope this answer saves you some time..:)

Comment: Yes, it did save me time. I would never have known to include the Image Texture. Thank you, Robin!

Comment: @Dr.Pontchartrain np! It would be possible, I guess, to get shot of the UV map altogether..  relying on the  fact that the diagonal of the quad is always going to be the longest edge of your triangle, and putting `center` at the middle of that.. (`dPdu` and 'dPdv`) give you tha actual World-space vectors of two edges.. see https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/196566/35559.